# facing problem while Connecting python script with mysql metastore in cloudera quickstart docker image

Tags: docker

Desciption: I am trying to connect my sql metastore of hive from python script on local machine.I am using docker image of cloudera quickstart to hadoop package.I am even exposing the my sql port(9083) while running the cloudera container but still it is not working.Am I exposing the port correctly or I need to do something else too

```
I am running the cloudera container using below command

docker run --hostname=quickstart.cloudera --privileged=true --publish-all=true --expose 9083 -t -i -p 8888:8888 -p 80:80 -p 7180:7180 -p 9083:9083 cloudera/quickstart /usr/bin/docker-quickstart

I am trying below python command to connect to the mysql db of cloudera docker image

db = pymysql.connect(host="127.0.0.1",
                     port="9083",# your host, usually localhost
                     user="hive",         # your username
                     passwd="cloudera",
                     db="metastore"
                     )        # name of the data base

Getting below error

Operational Error: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' ([Win Error 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)")


Expected Result:

    Python script should get connected to the mysql metastore db of hive
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `host="127.0.0.1"`, please use `host="localhost"` or `host="quickstart.cloudera"` instead.

Comment: I am getting below error after changing the hostname to quickstart.cloudera Can't connect to MySQL server on 'quickstart.cloudera' ([Errno 10109] getaddrinfo failed)")

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the `Host IP` address in MySQL string connection if you are trying to connect to external MySQL. Here `127.0.0.1` point to `localhost` of the container, not the `HOST`.

Change your docker command and set the `HOST IP` in the container.

```
docker run --add-host hostdb:HOST_IP --hostname=quickstart.cloudera --privileged=true --publish-all=true --expose 9083 -t -i -p 8888:8888 -p 80:80 -p 7180:7180 -p 9083:9083 cloudera/quickstart /usr/bin/docker-quickstart
```

Now update the MySQL connection string and set the host to `hostdb`

```
db = pymysql.connect(host="hostdb", # this will point to IP that we set in docker run command
                         port="9083",# your host, usually localhost
                         user="hive",         # your username
                         passwd="cloudera",
                         db="metastore"
                         )
```

**Managing /etc/hosts**

> Your container will have lines in /etc/hosts which define the hostname
>   of the container itself as well as localhost and a few other common
>   things. The --add-host flag can be used to add additional lines to
>   /etc/hosts.

[docker run reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)

Comment: Hi Adii,I got the connection details of mysql from hive-site.xml file of cloudera.quickstart docker image:Ran below docker command  docker run --add-host hostdb:192.168.100.30 --hostname=quickstart.cloudera --privileged=true --publish-all=true --expose 9083 -t -i -p 8888:8888 -p 80:80 -p 7180:7180 -p 9083:9083 cloudera/quickstart /usr/bin/docker-quickstart and then ran the py script db = pymysql.connect("hostdb","9083","hive","cloudera","metastore") .Still getting 2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'hostdb' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed error.Please help me with

Comment: Pls first verify from host machine first, connect from host machine using same 192.168.100.30 ip, for example incase of using mysql command if this is working then it should work on docker, `mysql - h 192.168.100.30 - u usrname - p `